# Using SQL REPLACE to update a column of text

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have 1000 SQL rows that contain a column with data type LONGTEXT. Each of these columns contains an incorrect phone number somewhere within the column. I have tried the code below to update the phone number.

```
UPDATE table 
SET text = replace('514-921-2738', '514-921-2738', '514-234-0315')
```

However, instead of simply replacing the first phone number - 514-921-2738 - with the second phone number - 514-234-0315, it replaces the entire text block with the second phone number.

In other words, all that remains after I run the code is the phone number. Clearly, I am not fully understanding how to use the `REPLACE` function but after looking at the online documentation, I don't see what I am doing wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL. I tried the suggestion below (now marked as the answer) and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
UPDATE table 
SET text = REPLACE(text, '514-921-2738', '514-234-0315');
```

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

> REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)
>
> Returns the string str with all
>   occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str.

In your query, you just replace the fixed string '514-921-2738' with '514-234-0315', and then assigning that to all text column values.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You said to use
SET text = replace(text, '514-921-2738', '514-234-0315'). What do I actually put in the second spot you have used the word text? The column name?

Comment: Yes, the column name.